# SwiftUI: UITabBarController that contains UIHostingControllers(rootView: SomeSwiftUIView). How to make full screen cover View

Tags: swift, swiftui, uitabbarcontroller, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a UITabBarController that contains 2 Items. FirstVC is UINavigationController that has UIHostingController a SwiftUI HomeView. HomeView has a navigationLink that can navigate to SecondView().

I am trying to implement a full cover view as a loadingView that gets triggered from SecondView().

Since my RootView is the UITabBarController what is the best way to access it in order to show a view on top of UITabBarController to cover everything??

**Solution should support iOS 13 and above.**

Thank you

```
        tabBarCnt.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
        
        let firstVc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: UIHostingController(rootView: HomeView()))
        firstVc.title = "First"
        let secondVc = UIViewController()
        secondVc.title = "Second"
        tabBarCnt.setViewControllers([firstVc, secondVc], animated: false)
        
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = tabBarCnt
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

HomeView

```
struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                Text("Home View")
                NavigationLink {
                    SecondView()
                } label: {
                    Text("Press here to go to second page")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("NAVIGATION TITLE")
    }
}
```

SecondView

```
struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text("Second View")
            Text("How can I make a modal view that covers the entire view and the tabBar ??? the View should get triggered from there. BAsically I want to make a loading view that covers everything.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `.fullScreenCover`?

Comment: @jnpdx I updated my question. Solution should support iOS 13 also and .fullScreenCover is available from iOS14 :(

Comment: Okay -- you can pass a reference to the tab bar into your SwiftUI view as a parameter.